# Call a function that requires a KeyEvent parameter

Tags: java, javafx, keydown, keyevent, keycode

I would like to call this java function in another function. How can I manualy fire a KeyEvent?

```
    private void chooseItemByKey(KeyEvent event)
```

I tried

```
        chooseItemByKey(new KeyEvent(null, null, null, null, null, KeyCode.DOWN, false, false, false, false));
```

to fire a KeyCode "Down" but my JRE told me there's a

`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`

The method needs the KeyEvent because I trigger it also by a key, but I need to trigger the function as well from another function whit out hitting a key on my keyboard.
Any ideas?

Comment: As it stands, your question makes no sense (you want to call `chooseItemByKey` so you tried to call `showAutocompleteListViewPartner`???), and additionally really doesn't have enough information (why don't you just make the method take a `KeyCode`?). Can you [edit] the question to provide enough information?

Comment: Sorry I copied the false method call. Of course i need to call chooseItemByKey

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refactor it so it calls a different method that takes just the `KeyCode`:

```
@FXML
private void chooseItemByKey(KeyEvent event) {
    chooseItemByKeyCode(event.getCode());
}

private void chooseItemByKeyCode(KeyCode code) {
    // essentially whatever you previously had in chooseItemByKey...
}
```

Then you just need to call

```
chooseItemByKeyCode(KeyCode.DOWN);
```