# Calling a function using key events

Tags: java

I am new to key events and am trying to figure out how to call a function when space bar is pressed. i included some pseudocode for what i am trying to do.

```js
public class scrap implements KeyListener {
  
    jump() {
        ///////////
        ///code////
        ///////////
    }
  
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e == Space) {
            jump()
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a function that requires a KeyEvent parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263360/call-a-function-that-requires-a-keyevent-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a Key Listener:

```
public class KeyEventDemo ...  implements KeyListener ... {
...//where initialization occurs:
    typingArea = new JTextField(20);
    typingArea.addKeyListener(this);

    //Uncomment this if you wish to turn off focus
    //traversal.  The focus subsystem consumes
    //focus traversal keys, such as Tab and Shift Tab.
    //If you uncomment the following line of code, this
    //disables focus traversal and the Tab events 
    //become available to the key event listener.
    //typingArea.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
...
/** Handle the key typed event from the text field. */
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e, "KEY TYPED: ");
}

/** Handle the key-pressed event from the text field. */
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e, "KEY PRESSED: ");
}

/** Handle the key-released event from the text field. */
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e, "KEY RELEASED: ");
}
...
private void displayInfo(KeyEvent e, String keyStatus){

    //You should only rely on the key char if the event
    //is a key typed event.
    int id = e.getID();
    String keyString;
    if (id == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
        char c = e.getKeyChar();
        keyString = "key character = '" + c + "'";
    } else {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        keyString = "key code = " + keyCode
                + " ("
                + KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode)
                + ")";
    }

    int modifiersEx = e.getModifiersEx();
    String modString = "extended modifiers = " + modifiersEx;
    String tmpString = KeyEvent.getModifiersExText(modifiersEx);
    if (tmpString.length() > 0) {
        modString += " (" + tmpString + ")";
    } else {
        modString += " (no extended modifiers)";
    }

    String actionString = "action key? ";
    if (e.isActionKey()) {
        actionString += "YES";
    } else {
        actionString += "NO";
    }

    String locationString = "key location: ";
    int location = e.getKeyLocation();
    if (location == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD) {
        locationString += "standard";
    } else if (location == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT) {
        locationString += "left";
    } else if (location == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT) {
        locationString += "right";
    } else if (location == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD) {
        locationString += "numpad";
    } else { // (location == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN)
        locationString += "unknown";
    }

    ...//Display information about the KeyEvent...
  }
}
```

I found this may helpful for you [Complete Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

Every key in the keyboard have unique key code.So you can check for pressed key, if it is equal to `32`(key code for space button) you can call the method.

Like this:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 32){
        jump();
    }
}
public void jump(){
    System.out.println("Jump");
}
```

Or you can check from `VK_SPACE`:

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
    jump();
}
```

Then you can add action to your button like:

```
scrap s = new scrap();
buttonVar.addKeyListener(s);
```